Use Microsoft Graph API to get information about current user in ASP.NET Core MVC app
I want to use Microsoft Graph API in ASP.NET Core MVC app to get information about current user. However, when the Graph Service Client attempts to fetch the user data in the controller (trying to populate entraIDUser variable), the request seems to hang indefinitely and never completes.
How can I resolve this issue and ensure the Graph API request completes successfully?
Here is what I have:

my app is registered with Microsoft Identity platform, and User.Read Delegated API permission is granted

controller function:


[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    try
    {
        var graphServiceClient = GetGraphServiceClient();
        var entraIDUser = await graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync();

        return View();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError("An error occured when trying to return Index page: " + ex.Message);

        return StatusCode(500, "An error occured when trying to return Index page");
    }
}


GetGraphServiceClient function that creates an instance of GraphServiceClient:

private GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
    var tenantId = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:TenantId");
    var clientId = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientId");

    var options = new DeviceCodeCredentialOptions
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        ClientId = clientId,
        TenantId = tenantId,

        DeviceCodeCallback = (code, cancellation) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(code.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        },
    };

    var deviceCodeCredential = new DeviceCodeCredential(options);

    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(deviceCodeCredential, scopes);

    return graphClient;
}


If you missed completing device code authentication by running URL in browser and entering device code value, the request runs indefinitely in localhost page and never completes.
Initially, I registered one Azure AD application adding User.Read Delegated API permission and enabled public client flow that is required while using device code flow like this:

To get information about signed-in user using Microsoft Graph API in ASP.NET Core MVC application, refer below sample code files:
HomeController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Azure.Identity;
using GraphMVCapp.Models;

namespace GraphMVCapp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var clientId = "appId";
            var tenantId = "tenantId";
            var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };

            var options = new DeviceCodeCredentialOptions
            {
                AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                ClientId = clientId,
                TenantId = tenantId,
                DeviceCodeCallback = async (DeviceCodeInfo code, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
                {
                    // Display the message to the user
                    Console.WriteLine(code.Message);
                    await Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };

            var credential = new DeviceCodeCredential(options);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes);

            try
            {
                var entraIDUser = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();
                ViewData["User"] = entraIDUser.DisplayName;
                ViewData["Email"] = entraIDUser.Mail;
                ViewData["Id"] = entraIDUser.Id;
                ViewData["UserPrincipalName"] = entraIDUser.UserPrincipalName;
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewData["Error"] = $"Error: {ex.Message}";
            }

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}

Index.cshtml:
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1>User Profile</h1>

    <div class="mt-4">
        @if (ViewData["Error"] != null)
        {
            <p style="color: red;">Error: @ViewData["Error"]</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 150px;">Attribute</th>
                            <th>Details</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>@ViewData["User"]</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email</td>
                            <td>@ViewData["Email"]</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Id</td>
                            <td>@ViewData["Id"]</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>User Principal Name</td>
                            <td>@ViewData["UserPrincipalName"]</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

When you run the above application, you will get below screen with URL and device code value in Console Output:

Make sure to run that URL in browser and enter the device code value like this:

In next step, you need to to sign in with your Azure AD user account:

Once the authentication is successful, you will get below screen:

When I checked the same in localhost tab now, it has information of signed-in user successfully like this:

